# "that threshold is vast"

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms

I've encountered this expression in DBZ Abridged, and I haven't encountered it anywhere else, save for occasional use on some forums. The context is the following:

"For God's sake, I bet even your father can do it--he's just not stupid enough to try! And as we've seen today, that threshold is vast."

I'm infering from this that the speaker is implying that the addressee's father is indeed very stupid, making the addressee's stupidity even more appalling. But I have no idea why the word "threshold" is used here, and how can one be vast - considering a threshold is usually a singular point or line, not something wide. Any help?

Comment: I see you are new to the SE. In case, if you liked the answer, you can accept it by clicking correct mark near the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must consider that not all lines have zero breadth.  Often times, you may begin entering into something and yet have to travel a great distance before you've actually entered into it.

Consider the English Channel.  If you are coming from France, it is the threshold to Great Britain.  Crossing that threshold into Great Britain is at the very minimum, an 18-mile seafaring journey.  Maybe 18 miles is vast, maybe not.  But that nonetheless illustrates that crossing a threshold isn't necessarily instantaneous, can require one to breach a distance, a distance that can, depending on the situation, be "vast."

So what the speaker is saying in that quote is that even from the point that being stupid starts, the point at which people begin to cross over into stupidity, they still have a long way to go before getting as stupid as that father.

Comment: Thanks, that last paragraph is indeed a bit enlightening. Though the fact that the father is in fact said to be NOT stupid enough to do something makes it all the more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make it clear that, `that threshold is vast` is not an idiom or a well known phrase. Those are just group of words.

First, let us understand both of the words ***threshold*** and ***vast***.

**threshold** [**<sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/threshold):

> The magnitude or intensity that must be exceeded for a certain reaction, phenomenon, result, or condition to occur or be manifested.

**vast** [**<sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vast):

> Of very great extent or quantity; **immense**.

So, when you say `that threshold is vast`, it means that someone/something has ***immense reaction***, or ***higher sensitivity*** or ***higher response rate*** or *** very sensitive towards feelings***.

For example,

> > "**Note that a dog's pain threshold is vast compared to a humans, so you may really have to spend some time examining closely. Use your eyes more than your hands -- attempt not to hurt the dog more. * Does this whining result in you responding a certain way.**"

Means, dogs are very sensitive than that of humans in perceiving pain.

Hope it is clear now!

Comment: Wrong threshold!!  A "threshold" is plank of wood or some such that provides a smoother pathway through a door.  Sometimes the threshold is just a thin strip, while in other cases it's a broad piece, giving the doorway and the room being entered a sense of greatness.

Answer (score 0):

Your inference is correct, a threshold can indeed be a singular line or point, but consider definition *1a* of [threshold](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/threshold) according to Macmillan Dictionary.

> a level at which something happens. For example, your hearing threshold is the level of sound that you can hear, and your pain threshold is the level of pain that you can feel without suffering or complaining

In the example given in the definition there is a range because everyone's pain threshold is different. Hence [vast](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/vast) can also be used to describe a threshold.

Comment: Ok, then how to put this whole expression into different words?

Comment: https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22vast+threshold%22&ei=9OR-W9WVHaOKlwTego7oCQ&start=0&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=662

Comment: I know what a "vast threshold" is, but what does it mean when someone says "that threshold is vast" seemingly out of the blue?

Comment: I guess "his limits of stupidity are wide"? What happened with the father earlier? - "as we've seen today"

Comment: Who is Trunks' father?

Comment: http://teamfourstar.wikia.com/wiki/My_Body_is_a_Temple%27O%27Trunks/Transcript

Comment: I've seen the script, I still can't make sense of the expression. I know Cell has a very verbose way of talking, but still, that one just feels weird and random, lol

Comment: I don’t know about the history between Cell and Trunks’ father. I guess Cell’s verbosity comes into play in the dialogue. :)

Comment: Trunks' father basically let Cell become perfect and increase his power substantially, thereby endangering the whole planet just so he could have a challenge. He had the semi-perfect form of Cell on the ropes, but got cajoled into letting Cell complete himself for the thrill of the challenge. Of course he miscalculated terribly, and Cell broke his spine as a result, pretty much. So yeah, he did something extremely stupid. But I still don't see it as a threshold into stupidity, more like actual stupidity :P

Comment: "that threshold is high" would be the more usual expression, as thresholds are commonly viewed as things you go over rather than past.